# Is it possible to see razor.g file?

Tags: blazor

Using Visual Studio 2019 is it possible to see myComponent.g.cs files? I notice that Visual studio code shows you those files only when there is an error in one of them. I would like to see those files just to learn how a *.razor file is compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now out-of-date. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179023/60761) instead.

---

Yes.

First turn on "Show All Files" in the Solution Explorer window.

Then open the `obj/debug/netcoreapp3.0/Razor/pages` folder.

Comment: This is correct, but I wanted to add that JustDecompile gives you a nice view as well if you decompile your app's .dll file https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx