# error the in razor.g.cs file, can't find in VS, can't find the _razor.g.cs file

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting "; expected" error in my `.razor` file and in `_razor.g.cs` file,

In previous blazor versions I was finding these `g.cs` files in the solution folder, now I can't find them there, and double clicking on the error message in VS doesn't point me to anywhere (error message has no line number, the one for .g.cs has a line number), and I can't find the problem.

Where are the _razor.g.cs files located now ?

Comment: the error was a missing `;` after `return <renderfragmentmarkup>`, for some reason VS has trouble showing me this line

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Edit the project file (.csproj) and add this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>   
</PropertyGroup>
```

The file will by default go to `obj\debug\net6.0\generated\...`

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, I got this exception when I named razor component the same name as my local model class.