# blazor dependency injection difference in .razor than in code behind .cs

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor

can someone please explain to me

why with

```
  @inject ILogger<Counter> logger
```

we have

[image]

and with

```
 [Inject] ILogger<Counter> logger { get ; set; }
```

we have

[image]

???
same DI system and diferent implementations ? i does no want to add nullcheck when i do this from code ?
thanks and regards

Comment: This is likely due to the Nullable flag being set to enable on your project's PropertyGroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you [look at the generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179023/60761), Blazor just adds a `#nullable disable` line:

```
@inject ILogger<Counter> logger
```

becomes

```
#nullable disable
[InjectAttribute] private ILogger<Counter> logger { get; set; }
```

But I wouldn't want that in my own code, so indeed the best practice is:

```
[Inject] ILogger<Counter> logger { get ; set; } = default!;
```

Comment: and what is recomended solution for custom my services? lets say i vave UserService
so if i do `   UserService us { get; set; } = default ! `  it yells at me that there is no target for default ?

Comment: A custom service should be no different from a standard one. So that error is from something else.

Answer (score 1):

The razor syntax is smart enough to know that when you `@inject` a service, it *MUST* be resolved. You cannot end up with a null variable - you would get an exception instead. That's why you don't need a null check in razor.

When you're using code behind files with properties, even though you add the `[Inject]` attribute, the C# compiler isn't smart enough to know that simply adding the attribute *guarantees* that the property won't contain a null value. The compiler doesn't know *where* the property will be assigned from, or even *if* it will be assigned.

The easy solution is to say "yes compiler, I know what I'm doing".

```
[Inject] ILogger<Counter> logger { get; set; } = default!;
```

Comment: Thanks
But in my opinion M$ devs should work this out. It should be identical and inject attribute should solve this itself.

Comment: The C# code that is generated from razor is pretty much identical. It also uses an `InjectAttribute` behind the scenes. However, it also disables the nullable context by inserting `#nullable disable`, which is why you don't see a warning. If you declare the property in your code-behind, it is up to you to handle this warning in whatever way you deem appropriate, since it is your code.