Can the code block be used before the HTML in blazor?
Blazor templates seem to follow this order to write components and pages:
@page "/users"

<h1>List of users</h1>

@code{
   // your code here
}

I am wondering, if there may be any known inconveniences on using the code block before the HTML. Therefore:
@page "/users"

@code{
   // your code here
}

<h1>List of users</h1>


You can even have separate files for code and HTML. I, personally, prefer having distinct files.

That is perfectly alright. Not being 'standard' is the only inconvenience.
You can have more than 1 @code block so you can put one before and after and even in the middle of the markup.
The .razor file is processed like:

a partial class is generated based on the filename
code from @code blocks is copied inside that class (in order)
code outside any @code block is collected into the BuildRenderTree() method.


To experiment, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179023/60761

You can even have html markup within a code block:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@AlertMarkup

Welcome to your new app.

@AlertMarkup2

@code {
    private RenderFragment AlertMarkup => (__builder) =>
        {
            <div class="alert alert-info m-2">Markup Inside a Code Block</div>
        };

    private RenderFragment AlertMarkup2 =>
        @<div class="alert alert-info m-2">
        More Markup Inside a Code Block
        </div>;
}

See Do I need __builder in a RenderFragment definition
